# How to get ID of Entity When Using Generic Repository Pattern c#

Tags: c#, generics, design-patterns, repository, entity-framework-5

Trying to figure out how to get the Id of the recently added entity when using Generic Repository pattern. An example would be nice. 
here's the Repository,

```
public class Repository<T> : IRepository<T> where T : class    {
protected DbContext DbContext { get; set; }
protected DbSet<T> DbSet { get; set; }
public Repository(DbContext dbContext)
{
if (dbContext == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("dbContext");
        DbContext = dbContext;
        DbSet = DbContext.Set<T>();
    }
 public virtual void Add(T entity)
    {
        DbEntityEntry dbEntityEntry = DbContext.Entry(entity);
        if (dbEntityEntry.State == EntityState.Detached)
        {
            DbSet.Attach(entity);
            dbEntityEntry.State = EntityState.Added;
        }
        else
        {
            DbSet.Add(entity);
        }
   }
}
```

entity.Id doen'st exist here

Comment: when you add the entity, its `Id` property will be populated.  you should provide some code.

Comment: I included the Generic Repository class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you step through your code, while running, you will see the `ID` (whatever you have it called) property will be populated after adding.

Your problem is, then, not with entity framework, but having a generic repository.  You need a way to return the (assuming again) `int ID` you just added.

Create an interface:

```
public interface IEntity
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
}
```

and have all your models inherit from it.  Then, change your type constraint to:

```
public class Repository<T> : IRepository<T> where T : IEnitity
```

then, you can return `entity.ID` after saving.

Comment: Started down this path  with the interface and after stepping though it I realized that the dbcreator wasn't using ID as primary key but some other field.  After Commit the other field was populated with the correct primary key.